# nginx-ingress within kuberntes / how to enable and use geoip?

Tags: kubernetes, geoip, nginx-ingress

Just realized that geoip was present by default within the nginx-ingress in the context of kubernetes; that is, looked around, being new into nginx geoip, I don't have much clue about how to benefit from this

Firstly, is there any declarative setup to effectively have it working ? A configmap setup, or so ?

Secondly, how such info is passed from the nginx-ingress to an app ? Is the info present in the headers ? is there any extra setup to apply ?

thanks a lot for any experienced input; best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [nginx_http_geoip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html) module creates variables with values depending on the client IP address, using the precompiled MaxMind databases.

This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the --with-http_geoip_module configuration parameter.

The module analyze headers, next connect to defined database, fetch the localization information and offers a variables regarding to them like
country or city of connection origin. Some examples:

**$geoip_country_code** - two-letter country code

**$geoip_city** - city name

**$geoip_postal_code** - postal code

Comment: could you explain how you build nginx with this module in the nginx ingress (kubernetes) context ?

Answer (score 1):

Find usefull documentation about how to configure Geoip2 for nginx ingress kubernetes deployment.

[Example Nginx Configuration ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-configuration/)

You will find the expected ConfigMap name at the nginx controller container entrypoint or environment variables. Furthermore you can override this name, the way to do so will depend on your nginx installation/deployment method.

[ConfiMap Nginx supported configurations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-geoip2)

You will find there a listed all the supported configs/properties plus a sort description about them and how to use them.

For this specific question, the property to configure Geoip2 is "use-geoip2" (link below)

[Enable GeoIP2](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-geoip2)

remark: you will need a license and add a flag at nginx entry command providing it